# React JS - is there a shorthand for this.setState(this.state)?

Tags: reactjs

Is there a shorthand syntax in React JS which could perform `this.setState(this.state)` ? What are the implications of calling `forceUpdate()` instead of `this.setState(this.state)` after modifying the state?

Thanks!

Comment: For starters (as stated here https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#forceupdate) `forceUpdate` will skip `shouldComponentUpdate`.

In general you should put any modifications of the state into either a `setState` or a `replaceState` call.

Answer (score 0):

assume you have a sideDrawer, your state is :

```
state = {
   showSideDrawer: false
};
```

when you click on the toggle icon, the bottom function will run:

```
sideDrawerToggleHandler = () => {
   this.setState((prevState) => {
       return {showSideDrawer: !prevState.shorthand}
   });
}
```

this was an example, I hope that will be useful

Answer (score -1):

According to [React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html), the state should not be mutated directly.

> Notes:
>   NEVER mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were immutable.
>   setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value.
>   There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may be batched for performance gains.
>   setState() will always trigger a re-render unless conditional rendering logic is implemented in shouldComponentUpdate(). If mutable objects are being used and the logic cannot be implemented in shouldComponentUpdate(), calling setState() only when the new state differs from the previous state will avoid unnecessary re-renders.